# Managing dependencies of Powershell modules

Tags: powershell

I have my custom Powershell script module, let's call it `PsHandyCmdlets`. In its manifest the following line is found: `RequiredModules = @('<Another module not necessarily installed yet>')`

The `RequiredModules` property is supposed to guarantee that any module listed here is imported into global scope before importing the current module. This would fail if that module can't be located on the machine.

Does Powershell provide a mechanism for ensuring that these modules are installed when `PsHandyCmdlets` is installed? If there isn't, is there a best practice in place for handling this scenario?

Comment: Do you mean installed from the PowerShell Gallery via the `install-module` command?

Comment: OK let me get that question in this way. Does PS installs the default modules with your custom modules? If thats the case, then the answer is it should be if mentioned in the manifest.

Comment: This is what #requires is supposed to be for. IIRC if the module is available PowerShell will try to load it when a cmdlet from that module is called. I don't have to import sqlplus module myself .. PS does that for me when I call `invoke-sqlcmd`. I still had to have it downloaded though. there might be other ways

Comment: @Mark, yes that would be the idea. `PsHandyCmdlets` would be in a gallery somewhere, and I wish to have it on my machine. Does `install-module` automatically go an grab any needed required modules? I haven'e read anything to indicate one way or the other but I'm leaning towards that not being the case.

Comment: @Matt, you're correct by naming a module in the `RequiredModules` property Powershell will load it for you.  The case I am concerned with is when `PsHandyCmdlets` is first installed. This custom module may require module(s) that don't yet exist on the machine in question.

Comment: This really sounds to me like it's something like a _peer dependency_ from the JavaScript/NodeJS world, where your module has a dependency that you don't need to ship _with_ your module because it's expected it should already be on the system. I came across [this article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-peer-dependencies-in-javascript-dbdb4ab5a7be) that explains them well.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good write up by Rene Hernandez on his blog talking about this topic and offers up some solutions. He also provides links to a PowerShell module (PSDepend) that could be leveraged to address this challenge. (link gone, but provided link to example)

https://github.com/renehernandez/powershell-dependencies-example

The module PSDepend was authored by RamblingCookieMonster which I have admired their work as being innovative and solid.

https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSDepend

Comment: First link is dead: https://renehernandez.io/notes/manage-module-dependencies-in-powershell/

Comment: Also, sadly, RamblingCookieMonster really hasn't maintained either BuildHeplers or PSDepend now in many years, and it's age and lack of TLC is showing. I love PSDepend, it works fairly well.

Comment: Also, the artcile that is linked to really doesn't answer the question at hand. It's merely attempting to address how to better source module dependencies during development, but not at "import time". I suppose one _could_ take a dependency on PSDepend to retrieve dependencies on import, I personally wouldn't want to do this and would want to ensure that any dependencies are bundled with my module, or are already installed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to your question is no. No, `Install-Module` will not install other "required" dependencies. It simply installs the requested module. And, as you stated from the documentation on the `RequiredModules` field of the module manifest, it is expected that the module exists and is imported into the (IIRC) global scope *prior* to importing the module that requires it.

There is another field in the manifest, `NestedModules`, that works a bit differently. It will import the "required" modules, albeit nested within the module's scope itself (as opposed to the global scope). This way, the required modules' functions are available to your module, but not necessarily to users of your module (unless you re-export those nested module members). However, once again, nothing "recursively" or transitively loads module dependencies. They must already exist on the system on which your module is installed.

But in your case, it sounds like you simply need to document in your module's README that your module requires "Module B" (and at that, the specific version or min or max version) to be installed and available (and possibly imported prior to importing your module). Or, if applicable, ship the required module as part of your module so that it is available for your module to import (probably via an `Import-Module` expression in the PSM1 file since the module will be installed alongside yours and module autoloading won't know where to find it).

Comment: The other approach is to write code into the module to install the peer dependencies if they don't already exist. Not a very clean approach to configuration management. I'm surprised that the developers of PowerShell didn't anticipate this. Node is a good example of how this could work, but I can't say I'm a fan of duplicating the same module. Nice write up.

Comment: Agreed, I think I mentioned that in one of my comments. But I also agree that this is not a clean approach. In fact, I don't think I would want to do this. Users should know what's being installed on their system. How would I know whether or not a module is trying to download and execute some malicious script? That's a security recipe for disaster!